# Trying to extract HTML between two style elements with cheerio

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

I'm scraping an HTML page but I'm trying to get one section of the page. There are no classes, id's or anything super useful I can plug into Cheerio I feel like (I'm new to this, so I know my ignorance plays a part).

The code looks like this.

```
<b> Here's some text I don't want</b>
<b> More text I don't want</b>

<hr style="width:90%; padding: 0>
<b> text I want </b>
<b> text I want </b>
<b> text I want </b>
<b> text I want </b>
<hr style="width:90%; padding: 0>

<b> Here's some text I don't want</b>
<b> More text I don't want</b>
```

Is there a way to grab the HTML between the two `<hr>` elements with Cheerio? Both elements are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start at the first hr and iterate next() until you get to the second one:

```
let el = $('hr').first()
while(el = el.next()){
  if(el.length === 0 || el.prop('tagName') === 'HR') break
  text += el.text() + "\n"
}
```

Comment: that `el.prop` method seems to be off... any clues?

Comment: You would need to adjust it for your specific html.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ascertain which nth to use you could try `nth-of-type` selector e.g.

```
hr:nth-of-type(1)
```

You might also be able to use `nth-child`